# how to generate the following list with few words in python?

Tags: python

I'm going to generated the points in each decade like

```
[3,6,9,30,60,90,300,600,900, .... 900000]
```

How can I do this in a most efficient way?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything inefficient yet?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe the question is misleading, I just want fewer codes. Thanks,

Comment: The question is fairly clear, but you should show what attempt you've made to solve the question yourself before asking for help here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about performance, but this is a 1-liner:

```
>>> [x*10**pow for pow in range(6) for x in range(3,10,3)]
[3, 6, 9, 30, 60, 90, 300, 600, 900, 3000, 6000, 9000, 30000, 60000, 90000, 300000, 600000, 900000]
```

On python2.x, `xrange` works as well:

```
>>> [x*10**pow for pow in xrange(6) for x in xrange(3,10,3)]
[3, 6, 9, 30, 60, 90, 300, 600, 900, 3000, 6000, 9000, 30000, 60000, 90000, 300000, 600000, 900000]
```

Comment: would `xrange` be useful in place of `range`?

Comment: Since op asked for efficiency in generation it's probably a good idea to make this lazily evaluated, but that only really makes sense if there's a large context for the problem.

Comment: @shahkalpesh If you're using Python 2.x

Comment: @shahkalpesh -- If you're on python2.x, sure.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus -- The title asks how to generate the "list", so that's what I went with ...

Comment: @mgilson The title asks how to "generate" the list.

Comment: @mgilson yea, like I said, my guess is that if there were some context for the problem it would make sense to generate it lazily, but given that there isn't any this is a fine solution.

Comment: Wow... what is that "inverted for syntax" called?

Comment: @NilsWerner -- It's a nested list-comprehension.  If you put each `for` on it's own line, you would see that the last one iterates fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(zeros):
    for i in xrange(zeros):
        yield int('3'+'0'*i)
        yield int('6'+'0'*i)
        yield int('9'+'0'*i)
...         
>>> list(func(6))
[3, 6, 9, 30, 60, 90, 300, 600, 900, 3000, 6000, 9000, 30000, 60000, 90000, 300000, 600000, 900000]
```

Comment: OP asked for ints, not strings.

Comment: Instead of casting to int, you wanna try scientific notation? `yield 3 * (10**i)` Or am I missing a joke here?

Comment: @2rs2ts I might be missing the point, but I thought this was making fun of a very poorly asked question without a wider context.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus Ah. It was so funny that I forgot to laugh.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generator for it:

```
def decade(n,m):
    dec = 0
    while dec < m:
        num = n
        while num < 10:
            yield num*pow(10,dec)
            num += n
        dec += 1

print(list(decade(3,4)))
```

the first argument is the increment in each decade, the second one the number of decades.